# Can't access Ubuntu through Windows Remote Desktop

Tags: ssh, remote-desktop

I have a laptop with Ubuntu Server set up and I can access it via SSH fine. So I installed XRDP and XFCE4, but I can't accesss it via Windows Remote Desktop. Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly does "can't access it" mean? It could be it times out, gets refused, says it doesn't exist, connects but doesn't respond, or quite a few other things.

Comment: Remote Desktop can't connect to the remoter computer for one of the following reasons ... Sorry for not explaining

Comment: Can you get a screenshot?

Comment: Remote Desktop can't connect to the remoter computer for one of the following reasons : Remote access to the server is not enabled . Remote computer is turned off. Remote computer is not available on the network

Comment: Read my comment below the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a remote computer, it's going to need to have the correct ports forwarded to it if you want to use RDP.

You need these ports forwarded for RDP to work:

```
TCP 3389
UDP 3389 #this seems to be optional
```

Comment: Like in this answer :http://askubuntu.com/questions/320121/simple-port-forwarding

Comment: @WKoppel no, it needs to be done in the router settings for the network the computer is on.

Answer (score 0):

Check if:

- firewall is not blocking port
- xrdp server is running
- port is forwarded on router (for connections outside LAN)
- you didn't misspelt IP address/hostname

Comment: SSH is running on port 22222 , should I check if firewall might block this?

Comment: And the guy who sent me the info for the SSH said that I can forward other ports via tunnel, but as I can't ask from him right now I am here.

Comment: Wait, is this a remote computer (not on your local network)? RDP does not use SSH. It has its own ports you need to forward.

Comment: Yes , it is a remote computer,

Comment: @WKoppel you're going to have to forward the ports RDP uses. I'll write an answer for that.