# How do I serve a website from a virtual machine on virtualbox?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, apache2

I have an Ubuntu 16.04 host that has an Ubuntu 16.04 guest running on virtualbox.
I have apache2 set up on both machines, they serve each their own websites.
I can reach the website on the guest from the host - that works fine - but when I try to reach the website on the guest from any other computer I get an error that the host could not be reached.

I'm using a bridge to connect the guest to the network. The guest can ping all other machines on the same network and also 8.8.8.8. All other machines on the network can ping the guest.
I've added the guest machine's ip in the host machine's /etc/hosts.

What do I need to do to be able to reach the website on the guest machine from the internet?

Comment: If you can access the website from any machine **in the same network** other than the host, then it's a network configuration issue. If only from the host then you probably need to change the network settings in the VM.

Comment: I've edited the question to clarify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As CelticWarrior mentions, Easiest way is to change the Network configuration of the VM in your Hypervisor (either Vbox or VMware or KVM). Whichever Hypervisor you are using, configure the Network connection to sit in the same network as the HOST, instead of Natted.

If you still want to NAT on your VM, or do not have the option to change it; you can configure IPtables to perform a Port-Forward to the VM's IP and port number. Using something like the following link:

[Simple port forwarding](https://askubuntu.com/questions/320121/simple-port-forwarding)

Answer (score 1):

In VirtualBox you can use as network adapter a network bridge.
Than your virtual ubuntu should get an IP address from your intern network.
(It is easier to give the IP manually so it is everytime the same IP)
Than you have to forward port 80 in your router to port 80 of the network IP from your virtual ubuntu.
If you than browse to your extern IP (you see it in your router) than you shall see your webside.
You dont need Apache in your host if you want to build a virtual server.

Comment: This is correct, and how I've set up my VM's (bridged).

Comment: The Web server on the host works fine. My router forwards port 80. What I need to do is to serve a different website on the guest vm.

Answer (score 0):

If having set up port forwarding or bridged you still can't connect to the guest's web server then possibly the guest firewall is blocking it.

For instance I was able to SSH to the guest OS instance but not connect to port 8000 where my guest was running a web service.

Using 'curl -v' I was able see that curl was making a connection and sending headers but getting no response.

So in my guest, which was centos, I put in a set of rules to effectively disable it iptables.

That fixed it!

---

Do..

sudo su -

Then..

iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT

iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT

iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT

iptables -F

Then try hitting the  address from the host again.

---

Other details...

My guess web service was running on centos and listening on 0.0.0.0:8000, ie all interfaces on port 8000. My host was Windows 10.

I had success with the following..

A) I setup NAT forwarding of port 8888 on my host in virtualbox to port 8000 of the guest. In virtualbox I did not provide an ipaddress for either the host or guest in the nat forwarding config. I then hit 127.0.0.1:8888 in the host and was able to access my site.

B) I also tried turning on bridged in virtual box then, after restarting the guest, I ran ifconfig  and found the network interface that was assigned a dhcp address by my router. This address was one starting with 192.168.0. as that's how my router is setup. Mine was 192.168.0.62 but yours will be different.
I then hit 192.168.0.62:8000 and was able to contact my site.

C) Finally I setup a bridged network in VMware workstation Player and did the same steps as B and that also worked.

In VMware player I couldn't see a place to configure the port forwarding so didn't try that. Probably need the paid version for that feature??