# To route or to NAT?

Tags: networking, iptables, nginx

I have an question regarding using **routing or NAT** between two nic´s on the same machine.

My set-up is as follows:

```
 VM - running Ubuntu 18.04    2 Nic´s:
     ens1 - 10.10.1.0/24 (Internal network)
     ens2 - INTERNET
```

I have a Docker-NGINX reverse proxy running that i can reach from Internal network. But I want to reach it on ports 80 and 443 from the second nic ens2 - INTERNET. But I don´t have a clue on how to achieve that.

I have turned on

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

but that did not do the trick, i think i have to either do some routing or NAT. But i don't really know how to achieve what I want and what´s the best solution to that?

I have red

[Simple port forwarding](https://askubuntu.com/questions/320121/simple-port-forwarding)

But that did not solve my issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple port forwarding](https://askubuntu.com/questions/320121/simple-port-forwarding)

Comment: If the referenced answer did not solve your issue, then we need more information about your system, local area network and such. IP addresses of your Docker and host and are they the same sub-net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured this out.

The problem was that I had dual nics and dual default gateways. You can only have one default gateway.
As soon as I commented out the default gateway from the internal nic and added static routes instead it worked.

Example from my Netplan YAML that works

```
network:
    ethernets:
        ens32:
           #INTERNAL NET
            addresses:
            - 10.10.1.65/24
            nameservers:
                addresses:
                - 10.10.1.4
                - 10.10.1.177
            routes:
            - to: 10.10.2.0/24
              via: 10.10.1.1
            - to: 10.10.3.0/23
              via: 10.10.1.1
        ens34:
            #EXTERNAL NET
           addresses:
            - 10.100.1.17/24
            gateway4: 10.100.1.1
            nameservers:
                addresses:
                - 8.8.8.8
                - 8.8.4.4
    version: 2
```