# How to forward port from Ubuntu to Windows 10?

Tags: ssh, openvpn, port-forwarding

How can I forward port 80/443 from Ubuntu to my Windows 10 port 80/443? I want to port forward from Ubuntu to Windows 10, I'm actually open to any suggestion on the best way to do it, I'm thinking of either with SSH or OpenVPN.

I have Windows 10 with XAMPP running Apache to host a website.
And I have Ubuntu 20 on Azure, what I want to do is if someone go to ubuntu-server-ip:80, the Ubuntu server should forward the request to Window-10-ip:80.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu!  Can you please clean up your question?  Can you add what version of Ubuntu you are using and is it a separate system than your Windows 10?  Can you give us more details as to what your actual goal is here?  Is your Ubuntu a Server or is it a client?  The more details will help us help you!  Thank you!

Comment: So, I am guessing then that you are looking for something like https://askubuntu.com/a/410467/231142