# Port forwarding for SSH via VPN

Tags: networking, server, ssh, vpn, port-forwarding

In short, I set up WireGuard on a remote machine, connected my Raspberry PI to it, and now I want a forwarding port so that I can connect to my PI via the public IP of my machine.

I tried to follow this instruction (https://askubuntu.com/a/410467), but I can't connect to my PI.

I entered these commands:

```
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d PUBLIC_IP --dport 50000 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.6.0.2:22

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

Where PUBLIC_IP - my vm's public IP

10.6.0.2 - the ip of my pi in the local VPN network

I have checked that port 50000 is open in my virtual network

I can connect to my PI via LAN

Are there any ideas why it doesn't work?

Comment: If it works on the LAN, then it works. Not an Ubuntu issue. Do not change any Ubuntu settings. Port forwarding should be on your router, forwarding to the VPN server.

Comment: Does your router properly forward to your PI? You shouldn't be able to connect to a wiaguard server in your LAN behind your Router without forwarding rules in your routerconfig.
Second: Where did you enter the commands ( which computer). Who  acts as server, who is client? How do your configs look like? 
Third: An often forgotten issue is the MTU. Reducing the MTU to 1200 often helped me. Add an MTU line in you wireguard config files.

Answer (score 0):

You need these commands I think:

iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp -d PUBLIC_IP_ADDRESS --dport 3389 -j DNAT --to-destination VPN_IP_OF_CLIENT:3389

iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp -d PUBLIC_IP_ADDRESS --dport 9998 -j DNAT --to-destination VPN_IP_OF_CLIENT:9998

iptables -I FORWARD -m state -d SUBNET_OF_VPN/24 --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

Change your IP address of the public IP that needs to host the forward (YOUR_IP_ADDRESS).
Change the destination (192.168.122.2:9998 for example) to the origin where the application is locally (VPN IP of your application)
Change the subnet of the wireguard in the last command.

How did you get a static IP setup in the vpn settings?
You'll need to make sure your clients get the same IP everytime.
Also, after reboots your vps might need to input commands again.

My commands work under Ubuntu linux.

praktical example:

iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp -d 50.7.80.10 --dport 3389 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.122.2:3389
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp -d 50.7.80.10 --dport 9998 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.122.2:9998
iptables -I FORWARD -m state -d 192.168.122.0/24 --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT