# Port Forwarding in Ubuntu Server 22.04 not working for me

Tags: networking, server, iptables, minecraft

I am fairly new to ubuntu and need help. I am running ubuntu server on my vps and home server. They are connected via Wireguard and I would like to forward the port 25565/tcp,udp to my home server. I tried many different versions of the prerouting command like [Simple port forwarding](https://askubuntu.com/questions/320121/simple-port-forwarding) and https://devstorage.eu/blog/linux-port-forwarding-mit-iptables/ but they only seem to work partly. I can connect to the minecraft server but time out on "Joining world". Pls help me and I am sorry if this is the wrong place to ask the question. I am quite sure that it is possible because I got it working on a Windows Laptop as home server and my vps but I forgot how I did it.

With these rules I encounter the "Joining World" problem:

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)

target     prot opt source               destination
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             ubuntu               tcp dpt:25565 to:10.7.0.2:25565
DNAT       udp  --  anywhere             ubuntu               udp dpt:25565 to:10.7.0.2:25565
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:25565 to:10.7.0.2:25565
DNAT       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:25565 to:10.7.0.2:25565

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
SNAT       all  --  10.7.0.0/24         !10.7.0.0/24          to:82.165.127.112
MASQUERADE  all  -- !localhost            anywhere
SNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             10.7.0.2             tcp dpt:25565 to:10.7.0.1
SNAT       udp  --  anywhere             10.7.0.2             udp dpt:25565 to:10.7.0.1
```

I tried:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -j DNAT -d 10.7.0.1 -p udp --dport 25565 --to 10.7.0.2:25565 
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -j DNAT -d 10.7.0.1 -p tcp --dport 25565 --to 10.7.0.2:25565
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i ens6 -p tcp --dport 25565 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.178.57:25565
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i ens6 -p udp --dport 25565 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.178.57:25565 
and socat: socat TCP-LISTEN:25565,fork,reuseaddr TCP:10.7.0.2:25565
```

these command lead to the "Joining world" problem:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i ens6 -p tcp --dport 25565 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.7.0.2:25565
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i ens6 -p udp --dport 25565 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.7.0.2:25565
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING ! -s 127.0.0.1 -j MASQUERADE
```

Homeserver 10.7.0.2/192.168.178.57 interface: enp12s0
VPS 10.7.01 interface ens6 + public ip: 82*

The ips 10.7.0.1/ .2 were assigned through wiregard and I thought you could use 10.7.0.2 and 192.168.178.57 interchangeably.

I want that when connecting to the vps public ip you would end up at 10.7.0.2 the homeserver.

sudo iptables -xvnL output:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
  150991 18835792 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:51820

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
  273154 551566308 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
      53     3381 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       10.7.0.0/24          0.0.0.0/0
```

sudo iptables -t nat -xvnL output:

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
      40     2088 DNAT       tcp  --  ens6   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:25565 to:10.7.0.2:25565
       0        0 DNAT       udp  --  ens6   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:25565 to:10.7.0.2:25565

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
      37     2345 SNAT       all  --  *      *       10.7.0.0/24         !10.7.0.0/24          to:82.165.127.112
      57     7372 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      *      !127.0.0.1            0.0.0.0/0
       0        0 SNAT       tcp  --  *      ens6    0.0.0.0/0            10.7.0.2             tcp dpt:25565 to:10.7.0.1
       0        0 SNAT       udp  --  *      ens6    0.0.0.0/0            10.7.0.2             udp dpt:25565 to:10.7.0.1
```

Comment: Show us what you have done and what is working and not working. We need a lot more details.

Comment: I also enabled port forwarding in sysctl.

Comment: It's impossible to read long code segments in comments. Edit them into your question.

Comment: Which computer is which? what is 10.7.0.1? 10.7.0.2? You edited out 192.168.178.57, what is that? which interface is ens6? Describe packet flow, and support that information with `sudo iptables -xvnL` and `sudo iptables -t nat -xvnL` so packet counters can be observed.